# How to set custom header logo on your Track Wiki project page?

Tags: documentation, wiki

How to set custom header logo on your [Track](http://trac.edgewall.org/) Wiki project page?
How to set custom header logo on special [Track](http://trac.edgewall.org/) Wiki page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [Project Logo and Icon](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization) documentation